# Time to repolarize a ferromagnet as a function of magnetic field strength

Tags: electromagnetism

What is the time needed to repolarize a ferromagnet to a new magnetization direction as a function of the magnetic field strength.

Please consider the two cases where 1) the magnet is not magnetized and 2) its magnetized to a certain direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Simple answer: "it depends".